# How to set two different sets of attributes for the <p> tag?

Tags: html, css

The first `<p>` tag has to use a background image and colored text in the Arial font written in the area. The second `<p>` tag has to use a background color and larger colored text in the Courier font.

I'm not sure how to go about doing this. It seems like you'd use `<div>` but I'm not sure.

Comment: It is best to post code that you already have so that we can help with exact scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Going out on a limb trying to guess what you are asking here;

add separate ids to the p tags

then in css

use each separate id to set the background color and text decorations and such.

Comment: or simply use classes for reusability :)